# Get Direct photo on Instagram

Tags: android, ios, api, instagram

I am developing on instagram. Now, I want to get all photo which are sent to my direct using API but until now, I could not find any way. 
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can use this api url to get your direct media:
https://instagram.com/api/v1/direct_share/inbox/

But for each request, you could only get 20 records, so if you want to get all direct media, you must to do a loop for send request many times by adding the parameter "max_id" into your request to get the continous data("max_id" is the value you got from previous request). Hope it's usefull for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *Instagram API* for direct share at the moment. The URLs they use from the app for the direct share page are as follows, first for the list of shares:

- https://instagram.com/api/v1/direct_share/inbox/

and second for the pending requests

- https://instagram.com/api/v1/direct_share/pending/

Comment: Any idea how to use that links without being logged in in the browser? For example with an access token?